# Код, который убирает все цифры из начала строки Python

Tags: python

Пользователь вводит строку. Если первый один или несколько символов - цифры, то их нужно убрать и вывести строку без них. Если строка изначально была без символов, то вывести ее без изменений. Кроме того, нельзя использовать "сложные" конструкции вроде regex.
Вот как выглядит мой код:

```
    text = input('Please insert a string: ')
    for i in text:
        if text[0].isdigit:
            new_text = text[1:]
            print(new_text)
        else: 
            print(text)
```

он при любых вводных просто убирает первый знак строки и выводит его столько раз, сколько составляет длина строки. Чувствую, что проблема в for i in text, но не могу понять, что именно не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас несколько ошибок:

- всё время проверяете 0-й элемент исходной строки, которая не меняется
- проверяете значение функции без её вызова, это всегда будет `True`
- печатаете результат на каждой итерации цикла

И одна погрешность (не ошибка, но небрежность):

- вы не используете переменную цикла

Исправленный код:

```
text = input('Please insert a string: ')
new_text = text
for i in text:
    if i.isdigit():
        new_text = new_text[1:]
    else: 
        break
print(new_text)
```